# Implement a WFS Server using Geo tools

Tags: wfs, geotools

I need to implement a WFS Server using Geo tools, I have an application developed in Java using a spatial database.  I wish to develop  a WFS service using GeoTools. As a first step, I am implementing the "GetCapabilities" functionality  and generating information in GML,  both GET and POST queries.

My idea is to use the Geotools classes, which will allow me to implement the following parts: Identification Service, Service Provider, Operation Metadata, etc., and then to generate a GML document to send to the client.

In using Geotools, the Geotools class started with GetCapabilitiesResponse (org.geotools.data.ows) and Class WFSCapabilities (org.geotools.data.wfs.v1_0_0).
Could someone please help me with a reference, tutorial or a sample code, to know how to use it?

Patrick Morales

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just use and customize Geoserver instead of coding all that from scratch?

Comment: The getcapabilities response is in XML not GML - as R.K says look at GeoServer (it's built using GeoTools) and consider making your application a WPS or custom datastore